# Terraform for_each Resource with Dynamic for_each

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, dynamic-programming

The issue is creating a Terraform resource using a for_each and then passing one of it's value into a dynamic variable.

Input data -

```
lb_rules = tolist([
  {
    "host" = "dest-1.example.uk"
    "name" = "redirect-host"
    "path" = "/"
    "path_pattern" = tolist([
      "",
    ])
    host_header" = tolist([
      "origin-1.example.uk",
    ])
    "port" = "#{port}"
    "priority" = 5
    "protocol" = "#{protocol}"
    "status_code" = "HTTP_301"
    "type" = "dev"
  },
  {
    "host" = "dest-2.example.uk"
    "name" = "redirect-all"
    "path" = "/"
    "path_pattern" = tolist([
      "/*",
    ])
    host_header" = tolist([
      "origin-2.example.uk",
    ])
    "port" = "#{port}"
    "priority" = 100
    "protocol" = "#{protocol}"
    "status_code" = "HTTP_301"
    "type" = "stage"
  }
])
```

And then feed that data into the following resource -

```
resource "aws_lb_listener_rule" "redirect" {

  for_each = { for r in var.lb_rules : r.name => r }

  listener_arn = aws_lb_listener.default.arn
  priority     = each.value.priority

  action {
    type = "redirect"
    redirect {
      protocol    = each.value.protocol
      host        = each.value.host
      port        = each.value.port
      path        = each.value.path
      status_code = each.value.status_code
    }
  }

  condition {
    dynamic "host_header" {
      for_each = each.value.host_header 
      content {
        values = host_header.value.*.host_header
      }
    }
  }

  tags = {
    Name = each.value.name
  }

}
```

The above works without the dynamic variable.

The error for the dynamic variable is

```
Can't access attributes on a primitive-typed value (string).
```

Is there anything obvious missing ?

Comment: 1. You are using `tolist` to convert to a `list` type, but it is already a `list` type. Also you convert to a `map` type within the resource. Is anything obstructing your from structuring the value as a `map` already to avoid these conversions? 2. The error arises because you are attempting to access nested values from the string element e.g. `"origin-1.example.uk"`. What is an example of what you want the value `host_header.value.*.host_header` to be?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
  condition {
    dynamic "host_header" {
      for_each = [each.value.host_header] != "" ? [each.value.host_header] : []
      content {
        values = host_header.value
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you anhhq, I had to tweak your idea and this is the final work solution -

```
condition {
    dynamic "host_header" {
      for_each = each.value.origin_host_header == null ? [] : each.value.origin_host_header
      content {
        values = [host_header.value]
      }
    }
  }
```

If the value origin_host_header doesn't exist, it is passed in as null, therefore the dynamic var is not created.